# Is it possible to continue the SSIS if one OLE DB source is offline? Always got this error

Tags: ssis, oledb

### TITLE: Package Validation Error

Package Validation Error

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Data Flow Task 1 [EA OLE DB Source [191]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "ea.prenlyn.net.ROWriter.RowReadOnly3P" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Error at Data Flow Task 1 [SSIS.Pipeline]: EA OLE DB Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Error at Data Flow Task 1 [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.

Error at Package [Connection manager "ea.prenlyn.net.ROWriter.RowReadOnly3P"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ".

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Created a data flow with 3 sources of db from different OLE DB. Just try to disconnect one OLE DB and SSIS will not proceed. Is there a solution to not include the OLE DB that goes offline?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if a data source is not available?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do it as it always validates the connection and the table before it starts. There is work offline option on the connection manager: this is an option I haven't tried but may be it is your only hope.